# Result of call to 'becomeFirstResponder()' is unused UITextField inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm trying to put cursor in first UITextField inside UITableView and let keyboard to be displayed as wrote like that.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

But warning showing like that.

> Result of call to 'becomeFirstResponder()' is unused

How to put cursor in first UITextField and let KeyBoard to be displayed?

Comment: did you override `becomeFirstResponder`?

Comment: Cmd+click on `becomeFirstResponder` and see if it takes you to the UIKit implementation of `becomeFirstResponder`. If not, there's your problem.

Answer (score 7):

I meet it when override 'becomeFirstResponder',if you want remove it,you can use 
@discardableResult

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Since `becomeFirstResponder()` returns a Bool, you are supposed to check the return value according to warning.

If you don't need to know `becomeFirstResponder` was successful, you should write:

```
let _ = cell.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: You can also just do _ = cell.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: Couriously, I am using `becomeFirstResponder()` everywhere and I get no warnings.

Comment: @Sulthan Do you have set special build settings, like `GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VALUE == NO`?

Comment: Nope. I get warnings for many other calls, not this one though. Trying to find out why.

Comment: @Sulthan: I think this is a mismatch between different Swift versions. In Swift 3, it should be a warning, but maybe some `@discardableResult` or `((warn_unused_result))` Objective-C-attribute has been used or removed UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe taking the delegate of textfield with respect to the content view of the tableView can help solve the issue.